# ASP.net Radio button click in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have asp.net radio button control in my application, I want to apply jquery click event on this control with class name. I have set CssClass property and made script with the class name,but its not working.When I inspect the HTML in firebug,its making the span with the CSSClass I have provided
This is my aspx code

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioyes" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Ques" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
  <asp:RadioButton ID="radiono" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Ques" runat="server" Text="No" />
```

its rendering in browser as

```
<span class="quest"><input type="radio" value="quest2yes" name="ctl00$ContentBody$Wizard1$Q2" id="ctl00_ContentBody_Wizard1_radioyes"><label for="ctl00_ContentBody_Wizard1_radioyes">Yes</label></span>
    <span class="quest"><input type="radio" value="quest2no" name="ctl00$ContentBody$Wizard1$Q2" id="ctl00_ContentBody_Wizard1_radiono"><label for="ctl00_ContentBody_Wizard1_radiono">No</label></span>
```

When I am typing `$(".quest").length` in console,its showing `0` as well.

I am trying with this

```
$(".quest").click(function(){
});
```

I also tried with

```
 $('#<%=radioyes.ClientID%>').click(function () {
});
```

but still not working,its not even showing any error in console

Comment: have you wrapped your code within `$(document).ready(function(){});` handler.

Comment: yes it's already inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .click()

You are assigning event handler to element before it actually gets loaded in DOM.

So you must use **event delegation** as,

```
$("document").on("click", ".quest", function () {
    // rest code here
});
```

### **<kbd>[.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 4):

You might be using the code before the dom element actually loaded to the page.

Wrap your function inside `$(document).ready(function ()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".quest").click(function () {
        alert('s');
    });
});
```